# how to load custom dictionary in marklogic using gradle?

Tags: dictionary, gradle, task, xquery, marklogic

I have to execute following custom-dictionary.xqy file using gradle

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace cdict = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/custom-dictionary" at "/MarkLogic/custom-dictionary.xqy";
import module namespace mem = "http://xqdev.com/in-mem-update" at '/MarkLogic/appservices/utils/in-mem-update.xqy';
declare default element namespace "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/custom-dictionary";

let $lang := 'en'
let $terms := <dictionary xmlns="http://marklogic.com/xdmp/custom-dictionary">
  <entry>
    <word>meeting</word>
    <stem>meets</stem>
  </entry>
</dictionary> 

let $dict-exists := <a>{cdict:dictionary-read($lang)}</a>
return   

  (if($dict-exists/*)
  then
    let $new-dict := mem:node-insert-child($dict-exists//dictionary,$terms//entry)
    return
      cdict:dictionary-write($lang,$new-dict/dictionary)
      else
    cdict:dictionary-write($lang,$terms)
,"Success"
)
```

and I am adding a task in build.gradle file to execute the XQuery module

```
task addDictionary(type: com.marklogic.gradle.task.ServerEvalTask) {

    client = mlAppConfig.newAppServicesDatabaseClient("databaseName")
    xquery = "xdmp:invoke('path of custom-dictionary.xqy')"

}
```

But getting following error

```
Execution failed for task ':addDictionary'.
> Local message: failed to apply resource at eval: Internal Server Error. Server Message: Server (not a REST instance?) did not respond with an expected REST Error message.
```

I am not getting where I am doing wrong. Is there any other way to execute an XQuery using a gradle task?

Comment: that error message is telling you that you are attempting to invoke the /v1/eval REST endpoint, but the application server is not a REST server. Do you know which port is configured for `mlAppServicesPort`?

Comment: Yes ,it is using port 8000

Comment: Try simplifying it to just get something working - i.e. set xquery = "fn:current-dateTime()". If that works, you know your connection is good. Also check the access / error logs for App-Services in ML.

Comment: I tried ,it is working , the problem I facing is only with xdmp:invoke function as when I run the whole code under xquery = "xquery code", then it is working fine